# IMPORTXML - Resource at URL contents exceeded maximum size

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have been using importxml to dynamically get data from a websource. I achieved this using multiple importxml formulas. The total no of rows is less than 200. But now I am getting the error "Resource at URL contents exceeded maximum size.". This URL contents are not larger than 200 rows.

Anybody have any tips. I may have to use google app script to replicate this. Does anyone have any helpful suggestions to achieve this? I am an amateur when it comes to google script.

Sample Spreadsheet located here.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bQqCpT-dn5ll09Rh07xC4Z3by1I3jkuk3qc3sA1iSBk/edit?usp=sharing

Basically. I am after all race details for today from the links in Col D of backend sheet.

For each event, I want to extract the following xpaths

```
Box, Name, Form, Speed, Rating, Rated Odds - //tr[@class="our-price"]. All separate columns
Overall Win, Place % - //div[@class="runnerRight"]/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]
TRACK/DIST WIN, PLACE% -//div[@class="runnerRight"]/table[2]/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]
BEST 1st Sec/Dist - //div[@class="runnerRight"]/table[2]/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]
BEST Time Trk/Dist - //div[@class="runnerRight"]/table[2]/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]
Box Wins - //table[@class="longFormStatsBox"]/tbody/tr[2]
Box Races - //table[@class="longFormStatsBox"]/tbody/tr[3]
```

Comment: While including a link to a spreadsheet could be helpful, the question body should all the required details. In this case you should include the formula, the url and also a brief descrition of your analysis of the source code of the websource.

Comment: The Spreadsheet is no longer accesible. Can you please add more information?

Comment: Sorry it should be accessible now. All the xpaths I used are in cell references so should be easy to follow. But I will add more details

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add a table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure.  If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455/) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.